# PHP double quote problem using Shell_exec

Tags: php, linux, vlc, shell-exec

I have some trouble trying to get a really long URL to work with shell_exec  when I add the quotes It doesn't work, but quotes is mandatory to get it to work.
For example.

```
iptv.php?channel=http://stitcher-ipv4.pluto.tv/v1/stitch/embed/hls/channel/5268abcd0ce20a8472000114/master.m3u8?deviceType=samsung-tvplus&deviceMake=samsung&deviceModel=samsung&deviceVersion=unknown&appVersion=unknown&deviceLat=0&deviceLon=0&deviceDNT=%7BTARGETOPT%7D&deviceId=%7BPSID%7D&advertisingId=%7BPSID%7D&us_privacy=1YNY&samsung_app_domain=%7BAPP_DOMAIN%7D&samsung_app_name=%7BAPP_NAME%7D&profileLimit=&profileFloor=&embedPartner=samsung-tvplus
```

The PHP file getting the long URL has to add it to double quotes and execute the command but is not doing it.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_GET['channel'])) {
    shell_exec( 'sudo cvlc -vvv "'.( $_GET['channel'] ).'"  >> /dev/null &' );
}
?>
```

When I watch the command result from the terminal using the command `watch vlc` it says `[01ec5d48] main playlist: playlist is empty`
It may be something simple but I can't see to find the problem.

The command to be execute should look like this after parsing.

```
sudo cvlc -vvv "http://stitcher-ipv4.pluto.tv/v1/stitch/embed/hls/channel/5268abcd0ce20a8472000114/master.m3u8?deviceType=samsung-tvplus&deviceMake=samsung&deviceModel=samsung&deviceVersion=unknown&appVersion=unknown&deviceLat=0&deviceLon=0&deviceDNT=%7BTARGETOPT%7D&deviceId=%7BPSID%7D&advertisingId=%7BPSID%7D&us_privacy=1YNY&samsung_app_domain=%7BAPP_DOMAIN%7D&samsung_app_name=%7BAPP_NAME%7D&profileLimit=&profileFloor=&embedPartner=samsung-tvplus"  >> /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this code, but please be aware, you have no sanitation, everything can executet in this way!

```
   
if(isset($_GET['channel'])) {
    $command = sprintf('sudo cvlc -vvv %s >> /dev/null &', $_GET['channel']);
    shell_exec( $command );
}
```

Comment: Is not working! and about the Sanitation comment, why the insult?

Comment: please be more specific, what means "not working", any error messages?'

as mentioned, if you not sanitize this input, you can inject all kind  of commands